Proof that a field endomorphism is an isomorphism or a null operator.
Let $\phi:F \rightarrow F$ be an endomorphism, where $F$ is a field. Show that $\phi$ is either an isomorphism or a null operator.
Attempts
Since $F$ is a field, there exists an unit, be it $1_F$, so $\phi(1_F)=a$, for $a \in F$. Note that since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $\phi(x)=\phi(x \cdot 1_F) = \phi(x) \cdot \phi(1_F) = \phi(x) \cdot a$. If $a=0$, then $\phi(x)=0$, for all $x \in F$, addressing the second option. If $a \neq 0$, since $\phi(x) (1_F-a) = 0$, and by the fact that a field is an integral domain, $\phi(x)=0$ or $a=1_F$. To avoid redundancy, consider $a=1_F$.
Can I assume that every $v \in F$ can be written as $v = n \cdot 1_F$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

This is not really true. Did you mean to write monomorphism instead of isomorphism? Look at $F(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ to construct a non-surjective monomorphism.

There's a counterexamole with just one variable: $F(x) \to F(x), x \mapsto x^2$

@LukasHeger That is a much nicer example.

The statement is false. You have shown that $\phi$ must be injective or trivial, however, it does not need to be surjective.
Consider $F=\mathbb{R}(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ and the map which sends
$$\phi(1)=1, \phi(x_j)=\phi(x_{j+1}).$$
This yields a ring homomorphism, but $x_1$ is not in its image.
Your statement would be true for $F=\mathbb{Q}$ or finite extensions thereof. That is because in this case $\phi$ would be an injective endomorphism of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space and hence a bijection.
Similarly, if $F$ is a finite field, then your statement remains true as injections between finite sets are bijections.

It's also true for algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$ or finite fields.

@LukasHeger Is there an easy way to see that?

I guess we can for every $a$ in the extension look at the subfield generated by the elements sharing the same minimal polynomial. This should give me an invariant subfield. As this invariant subfield is a finite extension of our prime fields they must be bijections. Something like that?

yes, that works. A slightly different approach is this: We know that a field homomorphism $\sigma:F \to F$ is injective. Now if the field is an algebraic extension of its prime field, then take any element $a \in F$. The minimal polynomial $f$ of $a$ has only finitely roots and $\sigma$ must map roots of $f$ to roots of $f$. Thus $f$ restricted to the set of roots of $f$ (in both domain and codomain) is an injective function from a finite set to itself and we win.

Actually this kind of argument is useful for example when showing that the algebraic closure of a field is unique up to (non-canonical) isomorphism: when you have two algebraic closures of a field, then a Zorn's lemma argument gives you the existence of a morphism between them. Now this kind of argument shows that it is surjective.

@LukasHeger Thanks. It's indeed much easier to look at the permutation of the roots. It shows that my class on Galois theory is more than a decade in the past :)

@LukasHeger You should write an answer including your easier example and more general results. It would add a lot of value.
